# class objects in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

i need to write a program in which main() would read a file(containing some predefined instructions) and create classes for each line and if a class object was already created, create a new class object..  something like

```
main()
{
     read file;
     save to a vector;

     for(i < vectorsize; i++)
          if(vector[i]== "book")
                 if(book b was already created) 
                       book c; 
                 else book b;
}
```

Comment: Have you read [your good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list)'s chapter on how to perform I/O?

Comment: What's the difference between `book b` and `book c`? What if you had to make 100 `book` instances based on the file contents? This wouldn't scale up very well and you probably want to add additional objects to a container (like, say, `std::vector`).

Comment: @biyyyree : thats what i had in mind.. but i want to update a book lateron how do i find it from the vector of a 100 booknames ASAP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) to store the created books. A map is a key->value store where you can adress the content by a own defined key.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Book> BookMap;
int main()
{
     read file;
     save to a vector;
     BookMap books;

     for(i < vectorsize; i++)
          if(vector[i]== "book")
                 BookMap::const_iterator alreadyCreatedBook(books.find(b.name));
                  // When there is no book in the map, the map returns it's end() element
                 if(books.end() != createdBook)
                       alreadyCreatedBook->second; 
                 else
                     books[b.name] = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a `vector` you might want look at a [std::map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C%2B%2B%29) where you can have the book name be the key and the actual book be the value. That way you can find the book you're looking for very easily.

Comment: I think the vector's meant to have captured the instructions read from file, which are then executed in sequence, so no need for a map. Not sure why they're not executed as they're read, avoiding the need for storage and iteration... :_/?  But, as Rudi also points out - the books themselves can be in maps.